# I need help evaluating the given function

Tags: integration, complex-integration, cauchy-riemann-equations

I was given the following problem and told to evaluate where C is the circle $|z|=2$ :

> $$ \int_{|z|=2} \frac{1}{z^2-1} dz$$

I've tried solving using Cauchy's Integral Formula and I got the answers $$ \int_{|z-1|=1} \frac{1}{z^2-1} dz = \pi i$$ and $$\int_{|z+1|=1} \frac{1}{z^2-1} dz = - \pi i$$ Any insight onto whether I’m doing this correctly would be helpful [here is a picture of my work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uK2QH.jpg)

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Ive tried cleaning up my question

Comment: The notations are a bit inconsistent with your picture and the work typed out, but it's generally correct so far. Now all you have to do is use those two residues to get the final answer.

Comment: thats where im stuck on do I just add them together?

Comment: what do I do then

Answer (score 1):

For this question, we can directly apply partial fraction decomposition, then we evaluate our integral using Cauchy integral formula.

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{|z|=2} \frac{1}{z^2 - 1} dz & = \int_{|z|=2} \frac{1}{(z - 1)(z+1)} dz\\
& = \int_{|z|=2} \Big( \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{z+1} \Big) dz\\
& = \frac{1}{2} \int_{|z|=2} \Big( \frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{1}{z+1} \Big) dz\\
\end{align}
$$
Since, the points are interior to the contour $C$, ie. $1\in(-2,2)$ and $-1\in(-2,2)$, we can evaluate the integral directly:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{|z|=2} \frac{1}{z^2 - 1} dz & = \frac{1}{2}\Big( 2 \pi i -2\pi i \Big) \\ & = 0\\
\end{align}
$$

Alternatively, you can apply the residue theorem as well. At (simple) poles $z=1$ and $z=-1$, we have the residues of $1/2$ and $-1/2$ respectively. Hence,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{|z|=2} \frac{1}{z^2 - 1} dz & = 2 \pi i \sum_{k=1}^K \text{Res}_{z=z_k} f(z) \\
& = 2 \pi i \Big(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\Big) \\
& = 0 \\
\end{align}
$$

(*Comments: Your steps are already off upon evaluating your integral. You do not need to change your contour.)

Hope it helps.